# Why does RxJS subscribe allow omitting the arrow function and the following method argument?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, operator-keyword

Recently I needed to use RxJS. I tried to design an error handling flow, but I discovered some weird syntax passing method arguments:

```
.subscribe(
    x => {
    },
    console.warn // <- Why does this compile, and warn 'is not 7' in debug console?
);
```

### Link to minimal reproduction:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6-5-error-handle-no-arrow-issue

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Use RxJS 6.5
2. Create a function return observable
3. Subscribe to observable
4. Pass parameter into subscribe
5. Just use `,console.warn`, not like `,error => { console.warn(error); }`

Without an arrow function, it still passes errors to console.warn. Why?

Code:

```
import { throwError, concat, of } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

const result = concat(of(7), of(8));

getData(result).subscribe(
  x => {
    console.log("typeof(x)", typeof(x));
    if (typeof(x) === 'string') {
      console.log("x  Error", x);
      return;
    }
    console.log("no error", x);
  },
  console.warn // <- Why does this compile, and warn 'is not 7' in debug console?
);

// pretend service method
function getData(result) {
  return result.pipe(
    map(data => {
      if (data !== 7) {
        throw "is not 7";
      }
      return data;
    })
  );
}
```

I tried to google some keywords, js, rxjs, angular, omit arrow function, argument missing,... but I cannot locate what tech is used here.

**Could anyone provide links to where this mechanism is explained?**

The following two questions are related but do not explain the behavior, just say "equivalent":

> The line
>
> map(this.extractTreeData)
>
> is the equivalent of
>
> map(tree => this.extractTreeData(tree))

[How to pass extra parameters to RxJS map operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500562/how-to-pass-extra-parameters-to-rxjs-map-operator)

[Why is argument missing in chained Map operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648218/why-is-argument-missing-in-chained-map-operator)

Comment: functions are "first class objects" in javascript.  it doesn't matter whether they are declared "inline" or referenced via a variable

Comment: `console.warn` is a function, it expects a function, so it's happy

Comment: thanks to everyone leaves the message when I ask question, let me figure out, I came from Java 8, and especially "functions are first class objects" is what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS [functions are first class objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function). When you have the code `console.warn` no brackets you have a reference to this object but you're not invoking that object, that would require braces `console.warn()`. For example you can do:

```js
let x = console.warn;
console.log('not happened yet');
x('test');
```

So your code is simple passing the `console.warn` function to the parameter of the `Subscribe` failure in exactly the same manner as you might pass any other function, e.g.

```
Subscribe(() => {}, () => {});
```

### [why] show Warn 'is not 7'

The other part of this is that your throwing an error `throw "is not 7";`. The signature of the error call of Subscribe is thus:

```
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

So the parameter of `error` is of type `any`. So the throw passes an `Error` to the error function handler. This is set as `console.warn` which has a signature of :

```
console.warn(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]);
```

`console.warn` essentially turns whatever parameter it's passed into a string, JS is not strongly typed and this is essentially down to [type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript), and logs it. the string of `throw "is not 7";` is `is not 7`. So it logs `is not 7`.

All in all I'd say this is all all a bit cryptic and potentially difficult to follow. There is nothing technically wrong here, but I would say it would make more sense to do the following:

```
.subscribe(
    x => {
    },
    x => {console.warn(x);} 
);
```

Based on the principle that ["Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand."](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler)

Answer (score 10):

First you need to understand what you're actually passing to the `.subscribe` function. Essentially it accepts three optional arguments `next`, `error` and `complete`. Each of it is a callback to be executed when the corresponding notification is emitted by the source observable.

So when you're using an arrow function, you define an in-place callback function.

```js
sourceObservable.subscribe({
  next: (value) => { },
  error: (error) => { },
  complete: () => { }
});
```

Instead you could define the functions separately and use it as callbacks.

```js
onNext(value) {
}

onError(error) {
}

onComplete() {
}

sourceObservable.subscribe({
  next: this.onNext,
  error: this.onError,
  complete: this.onComplete
});
```

Now this is what you're seeing. But instead of a user-defined function, you're passing the built-in `console.warn()` function. And in-turn the values from the notifications will be passed as arguments to the callback functions. So the value from your error `is not 7` is sent as argument to `console.warn()` which then does it's job (i.e. prints to the console).

However there's a catch. If you wish to refer to any of the class member variables using the `this` keyword in the callback, it'll throw an error saying the variable is undefined. That's because `this` refers to the scope of the function in the callback and not the class. One way to overcome this is to use an arrow function (we've seen that already). Or use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function to bind the meaning of `this` keyword to the class.

```js
sourceObservable.subscribe({
  next: this.onNext.bind(this),
  error: this.onError.bind(this),
  complete: this.onComplete.bind(this)
});
```

So if you wish to only have the error callback for example, you could explicitly state it and ignore the others.

```js
sourceObservable.subscribe({ error: console.warn });
```

---

Now as to your question *"why no parentheses in the function call"*, it was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15886327/6513921) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19732998/6513921). The arguments expect a reference to a function and the function names denotes their reference.

Comment: thanks also mention the "this" issue, it really helpful info if encounter unexpected behavior

Answer (score 5):

`console.log` is a function

function can be called with arguments in a bracket

`console.log("123")` means call function `console.log` with argument `"123"`

`tree => console.log(tree)` is also a function

it can also be called with arguments in a bracket, eg.
`(tree => console.log(tree))(tree)`

so a function with *callback as its argument* can call its callback with arguments in a bracket

```js
function example(callback) {
callback();
}
```

so if we pass `console.log` to it, `example(console.log)`, it basically runs as

```
function example(callback) {
console.log();
}
```

if we pass `tree => console.log(tree)` to it, `example(tree => console.log(tree))`, it basically runs as

```
function example(callback) {
(tree => console.log(tree))();
}
```

if you understood above code. it's easy to understand subscribe now.

```
function subscribe(nextCb, errorCb, completeCb) {
// ... got next data
nextCb(data);
//... got error
errorCb(error);
// completed observe
completeCb();
}
```

so your error callback `console.log` basically get called as `console.log(error)`;

`error=> console.log(error)` basically get called as `(error=> console.log(error))(error)`;

which in this case results are same.

Comment: The OP is passing it as `console.warn`(no brackets) so you haven't actually covered their scenario

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the three possible types of value an Observable is able to emit,

1. next
2. error
3. complete

These logic is translated in the arguments of the subscription function, so the first function callback will trigger the values emitted via next, the second callback the values emitted with error and the third function with the complete value.

In you case, console.warn is passed to the second function as a function that will be called  each time an error is emitted.

For the second question you can refer to the arrow function docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @Liam, Yes, I think you're right. I've made the respective changes

Answer (score -1):

Your subscribe expects 2 arguments. The first argument is a function that will be called with the "next" values and the second argument is again a function that will be called with if there occured an error. So, since "console.warn" is a function, you can just use it as a second argument.

`(error) => console.warn(error)` is the same as `console.warn(error)`

But be careful if since `console.warn` does not rely on the context "this", you will give no issues. But if you want to use a function that uses the context "this", you will need to use an arrow function.

For more info about JS scoping: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: "`(error) => console.warn(error)` is the same as `console.warn(error)`": no, it's not. `(error) => console.warn(error)` is roughly the same as `console.warn` (hence, OP's question)