# Why does 'event' work without passing it as an argument?

Tags: javascript

```
<button onClick="this.handleClick">

handleClick(event){
  console.log(event.target)
}
```

Why does the event argument in the handleClick function work without passing it as an argument? Does every event handler by defult create an event parameter?

Comment: "Does every event handler by defult create an event parameter" yes, a new one is created every time it is e.g. clicked.

Comment: you "give" `onClick` a function that takes the event as the fist argument. `this.handleClick` is a function. An alternative is something like `onClick="function(e){ handleClick(e) }"`

Comment: when javascript will call that handler function, it will pass the `Event` object. So you don't have to explicitly pass it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does RxJS subscribe allow omitting the arrow function and the following method argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187528/why-does-rxjs-subscribe-allow-omitting-the-arrow-function-and-the-following-meth)